# Is there any deferral for a Roth 401(k)?

Tags: united-states, terminology, roth-401k

When contributing to a 401(k) plan via paycheck deduction, one may contribute to an after-tax 401(k), a Roth 401(k), or (the *or* is non exclusive) a traditional (a.k.a. pre-tax) 401(k).

In one employer's Vanguard 401(k) plan, I read the following in the form where the employee specifies the paycheck deduction:

[image]

In the line `Roth 401K DEFERRAL`: what is being deferred?

I understand that for the `PRE-TAX 401K DEFERRAL`, the income tax is being deferred to whenever one withdraws the money, but I don't see what is being deferred for a Roth 401(k).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Deferral" for the 401k means that you're not collecting your pay immediately, but instead diverting it to a retirement account (Roth 401k in this case).

This [article](http://www.hbc-avl.com/Documents/ROTH%20401.pdf) defines deferral well:

> **What is the difference between a regular 401(k) deferral (pre-tax) and a Roth 401(k) deferral?**
>
> Under either a regular 401(k) deferral or a Roth 401(k) deferral, **you
>   make a deferral contribution by electing to set  aside part of your
>   pay (by either a certain percentage or a certain dollar amount)**.  For
>   a regular 401(k) deferral, the  taxable wages on your W-2 are reduced
>   by the deferral contribution; therefore, you pay less current income
>   tax.   However, you will eventually pay tax on these contributions and
>   earnings when the plan distributes the regular  401(k) deferrals and
>   earnings to you.  The result is that the tax on the regular 401(k)
>   deferrals and earnings is only  postponed.
>
> A Roth 401(k) deferral is an after-tax contribution, which  means you
>   must pay current income tax on the deferral.   Since you have already
>   paid tax on the deferral, you won’t pay tax on it again when you
>   receive a distribution of  your Roth 401(k) deferral.  In addition, if
>   you satisfy cer tain distribution conditions, then you won’t have to
>   pay tax  on the earnings either.  This means  that the distribution of
>   the Roth 401(k) earnings can be tax free not just tax  postponed.

Traditionally, this deferred compensation typically was directed to a 401k, but now that Roth 401k is another available option, deferred compensation can be directed there as well.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't the after-tax 401(k) contribution also be referred as a deferral then?

Comment: had to look it up.  The difference is in after-retirement treatment.

 * Roth withdrawls are 100% tax free
 * After-Tax 401k withdrawls have taxes due on earnings.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, yes - generally, any contribution from your pay that is diverted to a retirement account could be referred to as a deferral.